# PHP socket_recv() does not receive the entire response from the server.

Tags: php, sockets

I'm trying to receive an HTTP response using socket_recv. I'm having trouble with responses larger than 5000 bytes. It stops receiving; without throwing any errors; at about 7000 bytes even though Content-Length clearly says that the response is much larger than that (25000 bytes). I'm I doing something wrong or are PHP sockets generally unstable?

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
 while((socket_recv($this->socket, $buf, 1024, MSG_WAITALL)) > 0){
        $this->fullResponse .= $buf;    
    }
 if(!$this->fullResponse){
     $errno = socket_last_error();
     $errmsg = socket_strerror($errno);
     echo $this->state = "{$errno} {$errmsg}";
     return;
 }
```

Comment: PHP sockets work as designed. It is your assumptions that are 'unstable'. Where exactly does it say that `recv()` fills the buffer?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out why I'm unable to receive all the data. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

PHP sockets ignore Content-Length headers, because they are in the HTTP response section, and sockets work on a lower level. Are you trying to get HTTP resources? For that I would use cURL: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php, or if you just need to get a file do that:  file_get_contents("http: //www. example.com/ somefile.ext"), but to work allow_url_fopen must be true.
I also found this from the socket_recv comments section on php.net:
http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.socket-recv.php#47789